# Multithreaded Master/Slave in Python - Add or Remove threads

Tags: python, multithreading, threadpool, future

I want to implement a master slave multithreaded architecture where a master thread keeps refreshing a list of tasks that needs to be done by the slave threads. Sometimes, the list can contain new tasks, or other taks be removed, which means it has to update the slave thread list.

Is there a way to control the thread save list from the master thread? For example, if the task list after refresh doesn't contain the thread "5", it must be stopped and be removed from redoing it, while the others already in the threadpool are ignored, or it would create, start and add to the pool a new thread that doesn't have the said task in the pool.

The slave tasks are a while loop listeners that would eventually write in a DB.
Which is the safest way to stop a thread without crashing the whole pool?

Thank you!
PS: I'm sorry about the slave/master terminology, but I found the children/parent just as bad!

Comment: Your question seems to conflate "thread" with "task." FYI, a _thread_ is an operating system object that executes your code, and a _task_ is a program object, representing some piece of work that needs to be done. A task class typically will have some method that can be called by a _worker thread_ in order to actually do the work.

Comment: Also, unclear whether you are talking about periodic, recurring tasks, or one-time tasks, or maybe a mix of both. If it's a mix of both, then you might simplify things by managing the periodic tasks separately from the one-time tasks.

Comment: Re, "Is there a way to control the...list from the master thread?" All of the threads in a program can see and modify all of the same global variables. Plus, of course, they can see and modify any objects that they were passed as arguments. The trick is to prevent different threads from messing up each other's work when they access the same shared objects. We usually use `threading.Lock()` objects for that.

Comment: Thank you and sorry for my explaining. What I meant is each slave thread that will execute a while(something) based on the variables given from the master. Should the sthread finish the loop, encounter a server error(as it continuosly checks an URL) or throw any exception, the master thread must be informed about it and process that result. Besides the Database, there is nothing that the threads share that could have write-read race condition, or however it's called.

Comment: I also want to mention that I am intending to develop this in a OOP Class style, with a CustomThread class over threading.Thread